# What's the difference between the components ending in .system and .module in the Bug tracking system?

Tags: 7

I am a phd student focus on automated testing of complex systems and I selected the Drupal system as a case study. 
First, I need to examine the bugs recorded for a number of modules in Drupal. Thus, I looked in the issues of each module, e.g. File module https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=1&version=All&component=file.module . But, I noticed that there exist file.module and file.system components in the issues for Drupal. And, this happens with most of Drupal modules. Thus, my question is what is the difference between file.module and file.system in the issues. I need to recorded the bugs associated to each module, so I do not know if a need to consider the bugs of .system components or .module components or both.

Thanks in advance,
Best

Comment: I see [forum.module component](https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=forum.module) all right. But no "forum system" component. Can you please post a search link for it? Note: search links only works if you are logged in to Drupal.org site.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading things slightly wrong.

There's no `file.system` component, or any other component ending with `.system`.

There are systems:

- ajax system
- batch system
- file system
- etc...

These are for issues pertaining to parts of Drupal that are not located in a module. Anything in the /includes folder of a normal Drupal installation, basically. (ajax.inc, batch.inc, file.inc for the examples above)

Then there are modules:

- blog.module
- file.module
- menu.module
- etc...

These are for module-specific issues.

Comment: Thanks Clive for your answer. I thought something like that. But, six months ago I extracted the bugs from the node.module and now node.module does not exist. Only appears node.system. Do you know what happened to node.module? Thanks again.

Comment: I would _guess_ they've decided that the node module is involved in so much of Drupal as a whole that they've abstracted it to a sub-system, so you can report bugs about comment interactions with nodes to the "node system", for example. But I'm not positive. Sorry for the misunderstanding before by the way I get why you're asking this now